# How to Remove <a href> Link Tag for a Specific Value using Jquery

Tags: jquery, dom-manipulation

I have the following situation within a report that has the following `<td>` element. Please note that this can appear multiples times as it is a report.

My question is, when the value is ‘N’, using jQuery, I would like to remove the whole `<a href> tag` and just display the value of ‘N’ alone, without the underline below it, otherwise if the value is ‘Y’ then leave it as it is.

For example:

```
<td align="center" headers="MPA_CHANGED"><a href="http://www.mysite.com" class="my-mpa">Y</a></td>

<td align="center" headers="MPA_CHANGED">N</td>
```

Comment: Where is the value N coming from?

Comment: From a database query. Just need to check that if 'N' then no a href tag is required. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('a').filter(function(){
    return this.innerHTML === 'N';
}).replaceWith('N');
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4reE4/)

Comment: I just want for each row of the report, if the value is 'N' then no <a href> tag link is required. I am assuming I need a .each function?

Comment: He had a small typo. he fixed it.

Comment: @tonsils. Each jQuery core function works for every element in the set, you don't have to use `each` here.

Comment: @gdoron - tried your process and works fine but unfortunately when the report performs a partial refresh via ajax it resets itself. Is there anyway to make it fire always? Thanks.

Comment: @tonsils. Call it every time needed. like in the callback of every ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class name of your choice so that you can have more control over your td elements out of all td elements present: for eg: "report_td"

so html look like this:

```
<td align="center" class="report_td" headers="MPA_CHANGED">...</td>
```

Then try like this:

```
$(function(){
  $("td.report_td").each(function(i, e){
    var tdElement = $(e);
    var value = tdElement.find("a").text();
    if(value == "N") {
      tdElement.html("N");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').each(function() {
if ( $(this).text() == 'N') {
    $(this).replaceWith('N');
}
});
```

Comment: Why would you add exactly the same solution with different methods?

Comment: @gdoron Why do you care? Seems to me the beauty of it is that there IS DIFFERENT METHODS to get things done. Maybe the OP or others viewing this aren't familiar with the .each() handler and may learn from my answer.... Lighten up there Cowboy.

Comment: I care as a regular user, I don't like seeing a lot of duplicated answers when I seek for a solution to a problem I'm having. Of course you don't have to agree, just said my thoughts. good day sherif.