# Calling jQuery on Oracle Apex IRR partial page refresh

Tags: oracle-apex

Based on another question I have asked:

[How to Remove <a href> Link Tag for a Specific Value using Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13302268/how-to-remove-a-hreflink-tag-for-a-specific-value-using-jquery)

where I need to remove the a href tag if the value is 'N'.

All works fine on first load, but since I am using an Oracle ApEx Interactive Report (IRR) and perform a partial page refresh, the solution from my other thread doesn't fire again and so all my values that have a value of 'N' now have a link below it which is not want I want.

Within an IRR, is there a means of firing jQuery code, like on load when the report is partially refreshed, based on column filtering?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure is.

1. With dynamic action: After Refresh
   Triggering region: select your IR region

   True action: execute javascript code

   ```
   $('a', this.triggeringElement).filter(function(){
       return this.innerHTML === 'N';
   }).replaceWith('N');
   ```
2. Or just javascript code

   ```
   $("#ir_region_id").bind("apexafterrefresh", function(){
      $('a', this).filter(function(){
         return this.innerHTML === 'N';
      }).replaceWith('N');
   });
   ```

Although you might want to restrict your "a" selector to your actual link column. If you don't, every link in the IR region is selected. It's unnecessary.

```
$('td[headers="my_link_column"] a')
```

Comment: Thanks again Tom - should've realised.